# error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation

I try to get a VS2008 project to compile in VS2010 but I keep getting the error:

```
foo.obj : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in barr.obj
```

I'm getting this error only with the [libsquish library.](http://code.google.com/p/libsquish/)  which is included in the project.
It seams that it won't compile in debug mode and I don't understand why.

PS: I've been through several related threads on google before asking here